# Can't open Intellij on MacOS

Tags: javascript, java, macos, intellij-idea, ide

After installing the .dmg via Intellij website, when opening the IntelliJ Idea program, the icon bounces then disappears.

I was curious if anyone else has encountered the problem or would be able to help me get this installation going.

After trying to run it as an executable, it fed me back:

```
2020-02-10 19:00:13.661 idea[1023:22842] Current Directory: /Users/autonomous
2020-02-10 19:00:13.661 idea[1023:22842] Value of IDEA_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2020-02-10 19:00:13.661 idea[1023:22842] fullFileName is: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2020-02-10 19:00:13.662 idea[1023:22842] fullFileName exists: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP.app/bin/idea.vmoptions
2020-02-10 19:00:13.662 idea[1023:22842] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP.app/bin/idea.vmoptions
2020-02-10 19:00:13.663 idea[1023:22842] No content found at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP.app/bin/idea.vmoptions
Error: dl failure on line 542
Error: failed /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home//lib/server/libjvm.dylib, because dlopen(/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home//lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home//lib/server/libjvm.dylib: code signature invalid for '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home//lib/server/libjvm.dylib'

Failed to LoadJavaVM()
2020-02-10 19:00:13.664 idea[1023:22842] JNI_CreateJavaVM (/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP.app/Contents/jbr) failed: 4294967295
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have android studio installed? And what is the version of MacOS?

See here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000059910-JNI-CreateJavaVM-failed-4294967290

And here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004634719-Can-t-open-IntelliJ-on-MacOs

Comment: Perfect step in the right direction.
Idea is compatible with 10.11 and higher. I'm on 10.10.5. I'll try this updating.

Answer (score 2):

It was wrong InteliJ IDEA installation in my case.
Installing correct version as per my chipset helped solve it.

Answer (score 0):

execute following commands in the terminal

1. `sudo spctl --master-disable`
2. `xattr -cr /Applications/PyCharm\ Community\ Edition.app` (xattr -cr <<App_location>>)